# Link error while building with command scons compiler=msvc

Tags: qt, visual-c++, scons

I am trying to build a program using the command scons compiler = msvc. During this action a link error appears: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'QtCore4.lib'. I have installed Qt for Windows from http://qt.nokia.com/downloads (the free version) and tried to find the requested lib file, but only found the same dll file.

Any advice on how to proceed would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have built Ot using debug option. Without it creates all the necessary libraries.